# Shinkasen Help, what do I do?

Tags: tickets, japan-rail, kyoto, shinkansen

I bought tickets for the Shinkasen from Fuji to Kyoto via Bookaway but I had to buy another ticket from Shinagawa to shin Fuji at the Shinagawa station. However it was the same train to Kyoto. So we stayed on what do we do when we get to Kyoto?

Comment: So you have tickets from Shinagawa to Fuji and from Fuji to Kyoto for the same train? What exactly is the problem? At Kyoto you get out of the train and leave the station.

Comment: I believe that OP think the issue is that they didn't "start" or validate the shin-Fuji to Kyoto tickets because they didn't disembark the train.

Comment: Are you still on the train?

Comment: @EarlGrey, since Shinkasen is a bullet train, I don't OP ever had a chance to get an answer while in the train.

Comment: @ugoren what do you mean? LTE standard prescribes speeds at least up to 350 km/h, and the Shinkansen is slower than that.

Comment: @EarlGrey I assumed a proper answer is at least 3 bullets.

Answer (score 8):

You present both tickets at a manned gate, since the automated gates might not let you through. But you'll be fine.

Also, don't use Bookaway for JR tickets. They're an unauthorized third-party service and I assume charges a hefty commission. You can always buy a ticket at an automatic vending machine at a station, or if you really feel that you need to book in advance, try [Smart EX](https://smart-ex.jp/en/index.php), the official reservation service.